# Grunt-contrib-coffee doesn't write to output file (silently fails without throwing an error)

Tags: node.js, file-io, coffeescript, gruntjs

I'm using [grunt-contrib-coffee](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-coffee) v.0.7.0 with grunt v0.4.1.

I've declared my coffeescript task in my Gruntfile.coffee like this:

```
coffee:
  dev:
    'asd.js': 'asd.coffee'
```

In the same directory I have asd.coffee which contains

```
hello = 'hi'
```

and asd.js which is empty.

When I run `grunt coffee` in my terminal, it prints:

```
Running "coffee:dev" (coffee) task

Done, without errors.
```

But nothing is ever written to asd.js (or anywhere). What's going wrong? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to:

```
coffee:
  dev:
    files:
      'asd.js': 'asd.coffee'
```

Answer (score 3):

Also to verify what GruntJs is actually doing than you can always try:

```
grunt coffee --verbose
```

And see what files it is processing (if any)

Comment: Good tip. This could've saved me hours. :(